# clang: error: no such file or directory

Tags: xcode

Added JSONKit to an Xcode project and am getting this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ILGeoNames-develop/SampleApp/../JSONKit/JSONKit.m' 
clang: error: no input files 
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

However, the JSONKit files do appear to be there. E.g.

[image]

How do I figure out the problem (and fix it!)?

Comment: so in finder: CMD+Shift+G and entering '/Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ILGeoNames-develop/JSONKit/JSONKit.m' works and xcode cant find it? (/../ == go back one step

Comment: No, that path doesn't work which I guess is the cause of the problem. In finder, entering '/Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ILGeoNames-develop/SampleApp/JSONKit/' DOES work. Xcode seems to think they're in a directory parallel to SampleApp. I could move them to where Xcode thinks they are but, for me, the correct solution would be to correct where Xcode thinks they are.

Comment: I eventually fixed the problem by just deleting the files in Xcode and re-adding them. Would be good to understand why this happened though.

Comment: I faced the same problem. Nothing helps me: neither re-adding, nor cleaning project, derivedData, nor setting paths manually. Then I found out, that the path to the group, where I wanted to add my file, was path to nowhere. I set existing path to my group and than files were added correctly.

Answer (score 43):

You need to check Compile resources in the Target Project

You will Find that

> JSONKit

is in red color

just delete it and go

Comment: Just to be clear: It is "Compile sources" in the Build Phases section.

Answer (score 2):

you have to check 'copy files' when adding the group else they are left where they are and the path breaks when you move the project

Answer (score 1):

I tried re-adding files, but have no work.
So, I find the .pbxproj file in .xcodeproj, delete rows include the file name, then rebuild, success!

Comment: perfect solution. i added several time my files but couldn't resolve this problem. then manually delete all the entries from .pbxproj and then re-add the files resolve my problem. This specific problem usually occur after merging.